# Add the "revisions" link

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

My proposition is to add the "Revisions" link under posts.

P.S. I know that there already exists the "edited ... ago" link, but it would probably be more intuitive to have the "Revisions" link too (for new users).

Comment: What do you mean by '"revisions" link'? Do you mean something else than the "edited <timespan> ago" that leads to the revisions and is under the posts?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, the "edited ... ago" link exists. But it would be *more intuitive* to directly have the "Revisions" link. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Again, what is the '"Revisions" link'? Do you just want a different naming for the link, or a separate link target? Would the "edited <timespan> ago" stay or be replaced?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it should stay probably.

Comment: If you don't mind userscripts maybe Samuel Liew's [Post Headers & Question TOC](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#post-headers--question-toc) might be worth a look.

Comment: I also have a UserScript (in addition to the other two suggested here) for this called [AlwaysAccessPostRevisions](https://github.com/HenryEcker-SO-UserScripts/SO-UserScripts/blob/main/AlwaysAccessPostRevisions.user.js). I frequently (for moderation purposes) need to view the source of an initial revision which is a pain to get to on posts that haven't been edited. My UserScript adds [a small icon to the post voting menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Sba.png) which gives direct access to the revisions page for the post.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is crowded enough under the Post.

Users can click the Timeline to see edits as well, as does the `edited <x> ago` link once there is a revision.

We don't need more ways to achieve the same thing at nearly the same spot with the only benefit an even more to cluttered UI.

For those that still feel they desperately need that link: [Add Timeline and Revisions Links](https://stackapps.com/questions/8313)

Comment: "Users can click the Timeline to see edits as well, as does the edited <x> ago link once there is a revision." Indeed, this only works if the question has actually been edited. A lot of the time I encounter a question that hasn't been edited (or was only edited during the grace period), and I want to see its Markdown source. Of course I can do this by just clicking to edit the post, since in these cases the first revision is also the current revision. But it does create an inconsistency in the UI. The timeline view doesn't seem to offer anything useful here, either.